# can i access blob files in azure from ip and not a domain?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I need access blob files from ip and not from a domain because in a specific computer doesn't has internet conection, so i'll use a redirection. My question is can i access blob file from ip? for example:
ip.blob.core.windows.net/configuration/file.jpg

When i tried it, i received an error:The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server.

But if i use the account name or domain i can get the file.
myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net/configuration/file.jpg

I don't know if it is possible but, if yes, how can i do it?

Comment: You want to replace just the 'myaccountname' with the IP?  Is that your intent?

Comment: exactly! Just it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace only a part of a domain name like `myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net` with an IP address (e.g., `127.0.0.1.blob.core.windows.net`).  The reason for this is that domain names represent one or more IP addresses (e.g., IP address ranges).

A Domain Name Server (DNS) translates the domain name (e.g., `myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net`) to an IP address (e.g., `127.0.0.1`).  This is what happens when you make a request using a browser.

If you want, you can replace the entire domain name with a URL.  So, if you know the IP address of `myaccountname.blob.core.windows.net` (i.e., you know that it is `127.0.0.1` by checking it with the `ping` command or something equivalent), then you could make the request by using `<domain_ip_address>/configuration/file.jpg` (e.g. `127.0.0.1/configuration/file.jpg`)

Answer (score 0):

Azure storage is a multi-tenant service, and (I believe) you have no choice but to access it by dns name, since the service is dealing with proper request authentication, SAS, etc. And you're not guaranteed that a particular ip address will remain constant. You could always create a local `host` file to map the name, to see if that helps you...

Also, the format you showed (`<ip>.blob.windows.net/...`) is invalid - it would be something like `<ip>/...` - you cannot just insert an ip address into the domain name.